# CURL command to translate in Powershell or VBS

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I have a command in CURL which returns data. I tried to translate it to PowerShell or VBS, but I couldn't get any data and I have no error message in my code.

Following is my CURL command :

```
$Data = curl "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Brs-Xhr-Request: true" --data "class=Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos" --compressed
```

Following is my Powershell command :

```
$hash =@{
"class" = "Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos"
}

$JSON = $hash | ConvertTo-Json
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?" -Headers @{"X-Brs-Xhr-Request"="true"} -Body $JSON -ContentType “application/json”
$R.Content
```

Following is my VBS command :

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
strJSONToSend = "{""class"": ""Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos""}"
xmlhttp.open "POST","http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?",False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Brs-Xhr-Request", "true"
xmlhttp.send strJSONToSend
xmlhttp.responseText
```

I have a last issue, I'm trying to send a parameter "page" but the result is the same with different page number.

Following is the PowerShell command :

```
$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?page=2" -Headers @{"X-Brs-Xhr-Request"="true";"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"} -body @{"class"="Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos";"parameters[page]"="2"}
```

I don't know if the parameter has to be sent in the URL or in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salut Adrien.

Using PowerShell you can test something like that :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?" -Headers @{"X-Brs-Xhr-Request"="true";"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"}   -body "class=Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos"
```

I receive an answer, but I don't know if it's the one you are looking for.

Here is for the pages.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?" -Headers @{"X-Brs-Xhr-Request"="true";"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"}   -body "parameters[page]=2&class=Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos"
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup JP. Yes that's the result I was looking for. I have a last issue, I'm trying to send a parameter "page" but the result is the same with different page number.

Comment: How do you send the page parameter with Curl. Isn't  it using the URL ?

Comment: It's in both, URL and parameters, following is the request : curl "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?page=2" --data "parameters^[page^]=2^&class=Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos" --compressed

Comment: Thank you, I think your request & syntax are correct, but the response is the same if page = 2 or 50, I don't know why.

Comment: This question has been answered by JPBlanc, I'll ask another question for the remaining issue with more details.